# azure iot hub - urllib3.connectionpool SSLError with bad handshake

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm having trouble with the `azure iot hub device-identity create` command. I'm running this command:

`az iot hub device-identity create --device-id my-device-id --hub-name my-iot-hub`

But I keep getting a bad handshake error with SSL (see debug below). Not really sure why because I am able to go through the `az login` no problem.

I've tried the flag for Python library to allow insecure connection with no luck. I thought it was my work corporate proxy, so tried going the wifi route to a hotspot and that doesn't work either.

```
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/devices/cpl410-dev?api-version=2018-08-30-preview'): Retry(total=3, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
urllib3.connectionpool : Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /devices/cpl410-dev?api-version=2018-08-30-preview
```

I expect this to just connect, but I'm thinking I'm missing a certificate setup somewhere. Can anyone help? This issue is driving me nuts. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By any chance have you secured your Hub with X509 certificate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-get-started#